# Mobile-first media query iPad different to desktop

Tags: css, ipad, sass, media-queries

I'm building a site on mobile-first approach and I have 3 different designs.

- Mobile: width up to 767px  (red)
- Tablet:  from 768px up to 979px  (blue)
- Desktop: from 980px (green)

.

The iPad in both portrait and landscape mode has to behave as a Tablet design. (blue)

And then I have this media queries:

```
body{
  background-color: red;
}

@media (min-width: 768px),
only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {

   body {
     background-color: blue;
   }
}

@media (min-width: 980px) {
   body {
     background-color: green;
   }
}
```

The problem is that the iPad gets the desktop design (green). That is because the order of the media queries affects so it gets the blue and then the green because is coded afterwards.

I have found a solution that it would be adding an max-width for the tablet and reordering the media queries so the desktop would come first and then the tablet:

```
body{
  background-color: red;
}

@media (min-width: 980px) {
   body {
     background-color: green;
   }
}


@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px),
only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {

   body {
     background-color: blue;
   }
}
```

But I would like to keep the order like mobile, tablet and desktop if possible. Mainly because I'm using Sass and nesting makes it easier if it's ordered,

Any suggestion?

Comment: have you tried with max-width only ?

Comment: Well, it's mobile-first approach, so it has to use min-width media queries